# jvectormap markers onclick region active

Tags: jquery, html, css, jvectormap

How does one set the active region color upon clicking the region hotspot ( a `regionmarker`).

`onclick`ing the region I can currently set the background color using the below code:

```
regionStyle: {
          initial: {
            fill: '#be4439',
              stroke: "#fff",
               "stroke-width": 0.4,
               "stroke-opacity": 1
          },
          hover: {
            "fill-opacity": 0.8,
            cursor: 'pointer'
          },
          selected: {
            fill: '#1788c3',
          }
```

The plugin used is [jvectormap](http://jvectormap.com/).

Comment: Looks like there is an event called `onMarkerClick` and a method called `setSelectedRegions`. A combination of those may get you what you need.

Comment: you mean: how can be changed  the stroke color?